# Can I use proof of Irish citizenship that I don't have with me?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration

I was on a Tier 5 youth mobility visa which expired 25th June 2017 (nearly two months ago). I am currently back in Canada for the summer, but would like to come back to England as a tourist.

I have an document proving that I am an Irish citizen, however this documentation is in England. If I fly into the UK as a tourist, will I be allowed entry with the proof of Irish citizenship on the otherside.

Comment: If you're an Irish citizen, you automatically have the right to live and work in the UK visa-free, so why did you need a visa?

Comment: What kind of document is it?

Answer (score 7):

No, you are not going to be allowed entry to the UK by saying "I have proof that I am allowed to enter, but it's in the UK, can I just nip in and get it?". You need to have documents proving your right to enter with you.

If you can get someone to mail your proof to you from the UK (you mentioned you have friends in England), that would be allowed.